# How to Secure jdbc thin driver connection with oracle 11g

Tags: ssl, jdbc, oracle11g, ssl-certificate

I have oracle 11g as a server and desktop applications as a client.
I am using jdbc thin driver for connection(ojdb14).

I am new to jdbc thin driver secure connection.
Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc,-tlsv12,-jks-or-oracle-wallets  You're probably going to need to upgrade to a newer JDBC driver if you want to use SSL unless for some reason you want to use older protocols that have known security vulnerabilities.

Comment: You may want to consider using a more recent version of the Oracle JDBC driver; ojdbc14 means it is for Java 1.4.